# FFMpeg Split MP4 Clip Without Re-Encode | Out of Sync

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to split mp4 clip for certain seconds but i don't want to re-encode cuz my cpu isn't so good it's take so much time. When i try this code with encode :

```
ffmpeg -i clip.mp4 -ss 00:00:25 -to 00:01:20 cutted.mp4
```

it's working perfectly but i don't want to re-encode. So i try this code :

```
ffmpeg -i clip.mp4 -ss 00:00:25 -to 00:01:20 -c copy cutted.mp4
```

it's playing perfectly in media player with a couple blank seconds at first it's no problem i can cut these blank seconds when i editing it. But real problem is i can't edit that clip in premiere pro cuz it's out of sync. What can i do for fix it ? Any ffmpeg feature for that ? Thanks for all help!

Here ffmpeg output :

```
C:\Users\winuser>ffmpeg -i "D:\clips\clip_4579\clip.mp4" -ss 00:03
:00 -to 00:03:30 -c copy "D:\clips\clip_4579\renderless1.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-90155-g28924f4b48 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers

  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --e
nable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libblur
ay --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-
libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enab
le-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-li
bvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --en
able-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-
libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enabl
e-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-cuda --enable-
cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56.  7.101 / 56.  7.101
  libavcodec     58. 12.102 / 58. 12.102
  libavformat    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavdevice    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavfilter     7. 12.100 /  7. 12.100
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Input #0, mpegts, from 'D:\clips\clip_4579\clip.mp4':
  Duration: 00:04:14.78, start: 14149.499000, bitrate: 2287 kb/s
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, ster
eo, fltp, 164 kb/s
    Stream #0:1[0x101]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(pro
gressive), 1280x720, 60 tbr, 90k tbn, 2k tbc
    Stream #0:2[0x102]: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
Output #0, mp4, to 'D:\clips\clip_4579\renderless1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.9.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1
280x720, q=2-31, 60 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 16
4 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=
frame=  551 fps=271 q=-1.0 size=    4864kB time=00:00:21.23 bitrate=1876.7kbits/
frame=  814 fps=380 q=-1.0 Lsize=    7381kB time=00:00:29.98 bitrate=2016.4kbits
/s speed=  14x
video:6757kB audio:594kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxin
g overhead: 0.400338%
```

Comment: Try asking at https://video.stackexchange.com/, the stack exchange for video production